# ASP.NET Web Forms Switch from Site.Mobile.Master

Tags: asp.net, mobile

I have an ASP.NET 4.5 Web Forms Application utilizing Bootstrap.  http://goo.gl/GZZp9r

I had a problem whereby Site.Mobile.Master was being utilized whenever the website was being rendered in Extra Small ViewPort.  Since using Bootstrap I did not need this Site.Mobile.Master.

I had implemented a solution that would cause Site.Mobile.Master to not render, instead only utilizing Site.Master.

```
public partial class Site_Mobile : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var AlternateView = "Desktop";
        var switchViewRouteName = "AspNet.FriendlyUrls.SwitchView";
        var url = GetRouteUrl(switchViewRouteName, new { view = AlternateView, __FriendlyUrls_SwitchViews = true });
        url += "?ReturnUrl=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.RawUrl);
        Response.Redirect(url);
    }
}
```

The above solution is causing problem with GoogleBot because of 302 Redirects.

Someone has indicated that:
"when the user agent is Google mobile when your homepage is requested your site responds with a 302 redirect to

/__FriendlyUrls_SwitchView?ReturnUrl=/

and then the request is 302 redirected again to /

I have read that I cannot simply delete Site.Mobile.Master.

Is there a better solution to NOT render this Site.Mobile.Master for Extra Small ViewPort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the benefit would be to use this solution.

But hopefully this would resolve 302 Redirects that is bad for GoogleBot.

```
<browserCaps>
  <result type="System.Web.Mobile.MobileCapabilities, System.Web.Mobile, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
  <filter>isMobileDevice=false</filter>
</browserCaps>
```